# Can't access static resources on Amazon S3 with Grails Resources Plugin

Tags: grails, amazon-s3

I have a simple website and I uploaded all my resources (js, css, images, ...) on my Amazon S3 with public permissions

I modified my Config.groovy with the address of my bucket:

```
grails.resources.mappers.baseurl.enabled = true
grails.resources.mappers.baseurl.default = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket"
```

This the content of "mybucket":

```
mybucket/css/...
mybucket/js/...
mybucket/fonts/...
mybucket/images/...
```

But it doesn't work, and I don't know what to do now.

*Others questions (but not essential for the moment): what is the best practices with grails and Amazon s3 ? Should I use Cloudfront ?*

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE 01:**

After some tests, pictures work, but not the JS and CSS (because of the bundle ?). I read that the problem can appear where the next line is missing, but it is on my config.groovy

```
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

**Update 2:**

I just modified my config.groovy like that:

```
grails.resources.mappers.baseurl.enabled = true
grails.resources.mappers.baseurl.default = "http://xxx.cloudfront.net/static"
grails.resources.mappers.bundle.excludes = ['**/*']
grails.resources.uri.prefix = ""
grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*']
```

And it works !

**Update 3:**

The prefix is ok for CSS ans JS, but not for images...

Comment: You might look into the asset-pipeline plugin as an alternative to resources: http://grails.org/plugins/asset-pipeline

Comment: Thanks Andrew, i found a solution for my problem, but I'll definitely try this plugin later.

Comment: Please, post your answer (=

Comment: Hi Mr Cat. I updated my post. I don't know if it is THE solution, but it works for me.

Comment: And now, I want to use the cached-resources plugin, but I'm not sure that it is possible.